# Returning value from function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python (and programming) and was just experimenting by making a program to convert decimals.  I have defined a function as I wish to reuse it later in the program, but I am having a problem carrying the result of the function to the rest of the program.

```
print "For decimal to binary press B"
print "For decimal to octal press O"
print "For decimal to hexadecimal press H"

def checker(n):
    choice = n
    while choice not in ("B", "O", "H"):
        print "That is not a choice."
        choice = str.upper(raw_input("Try again: "))
    else:
        return choice

firstgo = str.upper(raw_input("Enter your choice: "))
checker(firstgo)

if choice == 'B':
    n = int(raw_input("Enter the number to be converted to binary: "))
    f = bin(n)
    print n, "in binary is", f[2:]
elif choice == 'O':
    n = int(raw_input("Enter the number to be converted to octal: "))
    f = oct(n)
    print n, "in octal is", f[1:]
elif choice == 'H':
    n = int(raw_input("Enter the number to be converted to hexadecimal: "))
    f = hex(n)
    print n, "in hexadecimal is", f[2:]
```

Comment: What's your question/problem/stacktrace?

Answer (score 1):

You need to save the returned value from the function.
Do something like this:

```
choice = checker(firstgo)
```

Then you save the result coming back from your function.

Every variable you declare, is only available at the scope of the function you declare it, 
so when you use `choice` outside of the function checker, your program does not know what choice is, and that's why it won't work.

Comment: Where do I add that line?  Within the function or out?

Comment: Out side of the function of course. This is your way to save the result of the function and use it outside of the function. As long as you use things inside of the function, you cannot use them outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
checker(firstgo)
```

You need:

```
choice = checker(firstgo)
```

As you have it, the value returned by `checker` is lost.  The `choice` variable defined by `checker` is not the same variable as the one defined outside it.  You can use the same names for different variables defined within different **scopes**.  This way you don't have to worry that the same name may be already used somewhere else in the program.